# RevMob "Caching Fullscreen failed for unkown reason"

Tags: java, android, revmob

I'm trying to add Revmob to my existing Android app, but receiving the following errors:

> Caching Fullscreen failed for unkown reason
>
> Caching Banner failed for unkown reason

Everything looks fine. The error report also contains that:

```
W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
W/System.err: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
W/System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
W/System.err:     at rm.com.android.sdk.a.b.a.a.d(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at rm.com.android.sdk.a.b.a.a.b(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at rm.com.android.sdk.a.b.a.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at rm.com.android.sdk.a.b.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at rm.com.android.sdk.a.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at rm.com.android.sdk.a.b.a.b(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at rm.com.android.sdk.a.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at rm.com.android.sdk.a.a.c.d.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at rm.com.android.sdk.a.a.c.a.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at rm.com.android.sdk.b.o.run(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/[rm]: Caching Fullscreen failed for unkown reason
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours looking for something wrong, I thought I'd take a closer look at the following line of error:

```
W/System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
W/System.err:     at rm.com.android.sdk.a.b.a.a.d(Unknown Source)
```

Going to revmob.jar file, is possible to go to rm.com.android.sdk.a.b.a package. It have an "a" class with a "d" method:

```
private void d() {
    Resources var1 = this.b.getResources();
    CharSequence var2 = var1.getText(var1.getIdentifier("app_name", "string", this.c));
    this.e = var2.toString();
}
```

Done! The error is because I don't have a "app_name" string in my app.

Since this string is not mandatory, I think is a RevMob bug, but just created one and everything works now.